# Load & Display Image in ActionScript

Tags: image, actionscript, load, sprite

I am typing with very green fingers, so, please excuse the question. Learning from examples, I have been trying to load and display an image in ActionScript. This is from the original example that I am working on:

```
...
...
var bmd2:BitmapData = bmd.clone();
var infoBM:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd2);
var back:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
back.name = "back";
back.rotationX = -90;
var bSurface:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
bSurface.y = int(...
bSurface.z = int(...
bSurface.addChild(infoBM);

var overlay:Sprite = new Sprite();
overlay.graphics.beginFill(...);
overlay.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, bSurface.width, bSurface.height);
overlay.graphics.endFill();
bSurface.addChild(overlay);
back.addChild(bSurface);

var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf...
tf...
tf...
bSurface.addChild(tf);
...
...
```

I am trying to place an image onto the bSurface instead of the text block, as above. So far, I've come up with:

```
var iSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
var iMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
var bmData:BitmapData;
bmData = new BitmapData(surface.width, surface.height, true, 123);

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
loader.load(new URLRequest("c:\pixlr.png"));
function onComplete (event:Event):void
  {
    bmData = Bitmap(LoaderInfo(event.target).content).bitmapData;
  }

iMatrix.tx = 0;
iMatrix.ty = 0;
iSprite.graphics.beginBitmapFill(bmData, iMatrix, false, true);
iSprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, surface.width, surface.height);
iSprite.graphics.endFill();

surface.addChild(iSprite);
```

...and:

```
var bmData:BitmapData;
bmData = new BitmapData(surface.width, surface.height, true, 123);


var loader:Loader = new Loader();
var location:URLRequest = new URLRequest("c:\pixlr.png");
loader.load(location);
bmData = Bitmap(loader.content).bitmapData;

surface.addChild(bmData);
```

but to no success. I've been failing miserably for days now, and would greatly appreciate some help.

Thanking you in advance,

Sofia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making this more complicated than it needs to be. A Loader is a DisplayObject. So when you want to load an image you can simply do this:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
loader.load(new URLRequest("c:\pixlr.png"));
addChild(loader);
```

You can use the onComplete event to handle any sizing or positioning, or fading in you might want to do.

Comment: Hello Plastic Surgeon, and thank you for the solution; it works perfectly. However, I had to place the image file in the same directory for it to work; is there any reason why a file path would fail? Also, your example worked well even without the event listener; what is that for, and is it safe to use the loader without it? Once again, thank you so much. Important thing is that it works now - after many, many, many useless and painstakingly ignorant hours of trial & error.

Comment: 1. The image path is "C:\pixlr.png" - you specified that path in your code above. You can use absolute paths, or relative paths.
2. The event listener is not necessary. It tells you when the image has loaded, so that you do not make calls on it before its there, and also, so that you could do things once its loaded, such as fade it in.

Comment: You're simply brilliant. Bottom line is you solved the problem which I had been unsuccessfully struggling with for days, and for that, I thank you sincerely.